# Find integer solutions to $x^2+xy+11y^2=p$ using Ring identities

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $\theta = (1+\sqrt{-43})/2$ and consider $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$, a principal ideal domain, with the multiplicative map $\psi (a+b\theta)=a^2+ab+11b^2$. Show there exists an integer solution to $x^2+xy+11y^2=p$ for $p\equiv 1\pmod{43\cdot 4}$.

I've tried several approaches. One was constructing an ideal based on $\psi$ with the intention of having it be generated by some $(a,b)$ such that $\psi(a+b\theta)=p$, utilizing the principal ideal attribute of $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$. Another was trying to more explicitly show that a solution must exist using $\psi$. However, I couldn't find a way to use the $p\equiv 1\pmod{43\cdot 4}$ property, and I didn't get far.

Pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know of the proof using Gaussian integers that any prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ can be written as the sum of 2 squares?

Comment: Yes I have. Here's my new attempt. We see that the polynomial $f(x)=(x-\theta)(x-\overline{\theta})$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}$, and that $f(x)=x^2-x+11$. Analogously to the proof of the gaussian integers, we need to show that $p|x^2-x+11$ for some $x$, and that this leads to a contraction, so p is reducible. I'm having trouble showing this. With the gaussian integers, it was $p|x^2+1$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, which is simple because $(-1/p)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}=1$ (Legendre symbol).

Comment: That's good. Note that $4(x^2-x+11)=(2x-1)^2+43$

Comment: Interesting. Nice hint, surprised I missed that. So we just need to show that -43 is a residue mod p. So we have $(-43/p)=(-1/p)(43/p)=1\cdot (p/43)=1\cdot (1/43)=1$. That should complete the proof, just need a bow on top :)